How to sort a list in Python to match an Excel Column?
I am trying to get a list of file names to sort with a specific column in Excel which has all the file names in it (though in a different order than file explorer has sorted them). The files are a bunch of images that I need to be sorted so that the data in the Excel matches the picture that is displayed. However, Python seems to only sort the first 10 files correctly then begins to, seemingly randomly, rearrange the last 20 or so file names.
As of right now my code is as follows:
import pandas as pd
import os

image_dir = r"C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Project\IMAGES"

file_list = os.listdir(image_dir)
imgarr = []
images = [i for i in (os.listdir(image_dir)) if '.png' in i]
for filename in os.listdir(image_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
        imgarr.append(os.path.join(image_dir, filename))

sorted_list = [i for i, i in sorted(zip(df["DESCRIPTION"], file_list))]

Which is giving me this output when I print(sorted_list)
[...'10973406 ^ MRE001.png', '10973401 ^ MRE001.png', '10973402 ^ MRE001.png', '10973403 ^ MRE001.png', '10973429 ^ MRE000.png', '10973427 ^ MRE000.png', '10973405 ^ MRE000.png'...]

However, when printing df["DESCRIPTION"], which is what the list needs to become, I get this order:
...
10     10973402 ^ MRE001
11     10973403 ^ MRE001
12     10973404 ^ MRE000
13     10973409 ^ MRE001
14     10973408 ^ MRE001
15     10973401 ^ MRE001
16     10973410 ^ MRE001
17     10973418 ^ MRE001
...

Disclaimer: I have only selected the 10th to 17th item on both lists as the list has over 30 file names and adding all of them would make this thread very long
Is there anything that can make this sort correctly?

Can you provide a [mre] of maximum 15-20 values that sort incorrectly?

Like what @mozway said, a small example of values would be great. Along with that, if you could provide/link to the full script, including how you access the dataframe then that would also be nice.

Additionally, with regards to that idea of a minimal reproducible example, it would be good if you cold provide the excel file and possibly a zip file of the image directory so that we can more easily reproduce the issues you're having.

as for the source code I sadly cannot share as it has other parts of the code are confidential, as for the data frame I am just simply using df=pd.read_excel(r"path/of/file"). I will find a way to make a minimal reproducible example and update.

Why do you need to create a list when you have the list of filenames in the dataframe, and in your desired order, already?

"it has other parts of the code are confidential" - you shouldn't be copy-pasting whole source code anyway. Figure out the simplest code that completely reproduces your problem, then [edit] your question to include that. Check out that "minimal reproducible example" article above if you haven't already.

@Fends –
Are there fewer names in file_list than in df["DESCRIPTION"]?

I think it's a better shot to inverse the problem and to get the data directly from the dataframe.
list_of_files = df["DESCRIPTION"]
list_of_files = [ i+".png" for i in list_of_files ] 

